# Regular Expressions - Kleene star

Tags: lexical-analysis, regular-language

What is difference between

```
 (0+1)* and (0*+1*)
```

Is there a certain distributing property I'm missing?

Comment: Well, I don't know if a star followed by a plus sign makes much sense.

Comment: `(0+1)*` means any number of `0`s or `1`s. `(0*+1*)` means either any number of `0`s or any number of `1`s. E.g. `1111` and `00000` are matched by both expressions, `00011` and `10100` only be the first one. `+` means “or” in this context, right?

Comment: yeah I think you're correct

Answer (score 0):

`+` [seems to mean “or”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) in this context.

> Many textbooks use the symbols ∪, +, or ∨ for alternation instead of the vertical bar.

And `*` (Kleene Star) means “repeated any number of times”.

- `(0+1)*` means any number of `0`s or `1`s.
- `(0*+1*)` means either any number of `0`s or any number of `1`s.

E.g. `1111` and `00000` are matched by both expressions, `00011` and `10100` only by the first one.

---

Here are the FSMs for `(0+1)*` (state p<sub>0</sub>) and for `(0*+1*)` (states q<sub>0</sub> to q<sub>3</sub>):

[image: p0 is an accepting state (the only state in this FSM), with a 0,1-transition looping back into itself. q0 is an accepting state, there are a 0-transition to q1 and a 1-transition to q2 (both accepting). They loop with a 0-transition from q1 to itself and a 1-transition from q2 to itself. Any other transition leads to the last, non-accepting state q3, including any transition from q3 itself.]

<sub>FSM diagrams made with the [Finite State Machine Designer by Evan Wallace](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/) (non-HTTPS link).</sub>